# Git: Merge a branch into master whilst master has no commits, and keep the revision graph separate

Tags: git

I created an experimental branch from master and made a few commits until I had working code. I then merged the experimental branch into master (master was still the same as at the time of the branch) but the graph in TortoiseGit and Source Tree now show them as one branch. For my own sake, is there a way to merge whilst keeping the branches looking separate, even if there were no changes made in master across the existence of the experimental branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use [`--no-ff` to prevent Git from making a *fast forward merge*](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge.html#_fast_forward_merge):

> ### FAST-FORWARD MERGE
>
> Often the current branch head is an ancestor of the named commit. This is the most common case especially when invoked from *git pull*: you are tracking an upstream repository, you have committed no local changes, and now you want to update to a newer upstream revision. In this case, a new commit is not needed to store the combined history; instead, the
>
> ```
> HEAD
> ```
>
> (along with the index) is updated to point at the named commit, without creating an extra merge commit.
>
> This behavior can be suppressed with the
>
> ```
> --no-ff
> ```
>
> option.